# How Microsoft teams custom app version upgrade is visible to end users?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-api

I have a Microsoft teams custom app which is already available to customers on teams app marketplace. We have upgraded the manifest version and next step would be to submit the application for production release.

Once Microsoft approves it, How will this app be available to end users since admin approval is required for app update?

In our version upgrade no new permission set is added but how will it be visible in both:

- If no new permission is added?
- If there are new set of permissions are added?

Will there be a prompt from teams end?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official document, it shows that when you do some changes for custom app in Teams admin center, it will take up to 24 hours for the end users to see the changes. You can try to wait for 24 hours to see if it can change.
For more details, you can refer to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/customize-apps#frequently-asked-questions

In most cases, after you complete an app update the new version automatically appears for end users.
However, there are some updates to the Microsoft Teams manifest that require user acceptance to complete.
For more details, you can refer to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/upload-custom-apps#end-user-update-experience